# Prove that the preimage of a closed set under a continuous mapping is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a problem with this:

> Let $f:\:\mathbb{R\rightarrow\mathbb{R}}$ be a continuous function. Prove that if $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set then $f^{-1}\left(D\right)$ is closed.

I don't know how start this prove, i was thinking about that:

$f^{-1}(D)=\left\{ x\epsilon E\,:\,f(E)\epsilon D\right\} $... But i don't know how prove this exercise, anything help!! Thanks for all!

Comment: Take the definition of a continuous function, and consider $\mathbb{R} - D$ as your open set.

Answer (score 0):

You prove $\mathbb{R} - f^{-1}(D)$ to be open. Thus let $x \in \mathbb{R}-f^{-1}(D)\implies x \notin f^{-1}(D)\implies f(x) \notin D\implies f(x) \in \mathbb{R} - D\implies f(x) \in (f(x)-r,f(x)+r)\subset \mathbb{R}-D$ for some $r > 0$. Thus $x \in f^{-1}((f(x)-r,f(x)+r))\subset f^{-1}\left(\mathbb{R}-D\right)= \mathbb{R}-f^{-1}(D)\implies \mathbb{R}-f^{-1}(D)$ is open $\implies f^{-1}(D)$ is closed.